# Proving an absence of rational and integer solutions.

Tags: diophantine-equations, rational-numbers, integers

Prove $$(x+y\sqrt2)^2+(z+t\sqrt2)^2=5+4\sqrt2$$
 has no solution in rational $(x,y,z,t)$

Prove $$(5+3\sqrt2)^m=(3+5\sqrt2)^n$$ 
has no solution for positive integers $(m,n)$

How do I approach these kinds of problems? I'm not sure where to start. Also, what are some more problems in this category to practice?

Comment: This seems like algebra on $\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$ to me

Comment: For the first one, I would start by multiplying it out, collecting all terms with containing $\sqrt{2}$,  then equating rational an irrational parts.

Comment: @vrugtehagel These are problems from M&IQ 1992 so they should be solvable without tools from abstract algebra and group theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking conjugates in $(5+3\sqrt2)^m=(3+5\sqrt2)^n$, we get $(5-3\sqrt2)^m=(3-5\sqrt2)^n$. Now multiply these two equations to obtain $7^m = (-41)^n$, an impossibility.

Using the same technique in $$(x+y\sqrt2)^2+(z+t\sqrt2)^2=5+4\sqrt2$$ we get
$$(x-y\sqrt2)^2+(z-t\sqrt2)^2=5-4\sqrt2$$
Multiplying these, we get
$$((x+y\sqrt2)^2+(z+t\sqrt2)^2)((x-y\sqrt2)^2+(z-t\sqrt2)^2)= -7 $$
impossible since the left hand side is positive.

Comment: So, this answer depends on the fact that conjugation is a field isomorphism, right? What other justification is there for the fact that "taking conjugates" is a legitimate move?

Comment: Nice solution! I didn't expect such a simple solution.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs In a way, yes. If $a, b, c, d$ are rational and $a+b\sqrt{2} = c+d\sqrt{2}$, then $a-b\sqrt{2} = c-d\sqrt{2}$. This can be proved using the fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational.

Comment: Well, if $a+b\sqrt{2}=c+d\sqrt{2}$, then $a=c$ and $b=d$. There's more than that to being a field isomorphism, though. We also need that the conjugate of a product is the product of conjugates, the conjugate of a power is the power of the conjugate, etc.

Comment: For the first problem, we are deriving $(x-y\sqrt2)^2+(z-t\sqrt2)^2=5-4\sqrt2$ from $(x+y\sqrt2)^2+(z+t\sqrt2)^2=5+4\sqrt2$ and hence we do not need field isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint for the second part:* Take norms: $N(a+b\sqrt2)=a^2-2b^2$. The key property is $N(\alpha\beta)=N(\alpha)N(\beta)$.

Comment: You get $7^m=(-41)^n$ which has no solutions. I know that norms makes the problem trivial but this should be solvable without norms since it's an M&IQ problem.